# Rails subscription limitations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I have an application with set limits on subscription attributes i/e a user can have five projects for subscription A but have ten for subscription B

At present I run a check on there current usage when linking to the create action and if they are over there limit I do not display the link to create a new project. On the view (for the new project ) I again run the check (in a helper) to see if they can create a new project and if they are not I display a message stating so and a little upgrade link.

Is this a secure method of stopping a user bypassing there subscription attribute limitations ?

What about direct PUT requests etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also validate that the user's subscription allows starting a new project when a new project is created. This guarantee that even if they posted directly to the new_project_path they would get an error.

```
class Project

  belongs_to :user

  validate_on_create :subscription_allows_new_project

  def subscription_allows_new_project
    unless self.user.subscription.max_projects > self.user.projects.count
      errors.add_to_base("Project limit reached, please upgrade today!")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Very simple  and so obvious now you have written it :)

Comment: This is actually a pretty elegant solution for this problem. Would any of you happen to have a similar solution to the problem I am having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631218/how-do-i-access-a-user-with-a-specific-role-in-rails-3  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really cautious about the put requests, you could simply create a helper method that you call in all of the pages.

```
<% if has_user_hit_project_limits %>
Upgrade Now!
<% else %>
Add project
<% end %>

def has_user_hit_project_limits
    if #logic
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```